# How to specify the type of the computed column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table, sql-server-2017, alter-table

I have a table with a `payment decimal(5, 2)` column and I want to add a computed column to a table:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl
ADD colComputed AS (ROUND(payment , 0)) / 0.6)) PERSISTED
```

This works, however, `colComputed` ends up being `numeric(12, 6)`.

I tried specifying `ALTER TABLE tbl ADD colComputed decimal(5, 2) AS ...`, but it appears to be invalid syntax.  How can I force the computed column to be `decimal(5, 2)`?

Comment: What about `colComputed AS CAST(ROUND(payment , 0)) / 0.6)) AS decimal(5, 2))`?

Comment: Don't forget to specify `PERSISTED NOT NULL` too.

Comment: @GMB You have an extraneous parenthesis in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `cast` in the definition of the column itself:

```
alter table tbl add colComputed as 
  cast( round(payment, 0) / 0.6 as decimal(5, 2)) persisted;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ljocAYmd)**:

```
create table tbl(id int primary key, payment decimal(12, 6));
insert into tbl values (1, 11), (2, 15);

alter table tbl add colComputed as 
  cast( round(payment, 0) / 0.6 as decimal(5, 2) ) persisted;
  
select t.*, round(payment, 0) / 0.6 rawComputed
from tbl t
```

| id | payment | colComputed | rawComputed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11.000000 | 18.33 | 18.33333333 |
| 2 | 15.000000 | 25.00 | 25.00000000 |